# Why is this variable from the Redux store not in the `this.props` on React page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, reduce

I have a variable that I believe is correctly written to my Redux store using a Redux action and reducer. But for some reason it never becomes part of the props on a React page. What could be the cause, given the code below?
I would expect `this.props.transactionDetails` and `this.state.trans_status` to be available within the `render` code block. The Redux store is functioning correctly for other variables/pages.

React Page:

```
import { get_details } from "../../../appRedux/actions/transAction";

class DonePage extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            showLoader: true,
            transactionDetails: "",
            trans_status: "",
        };
    }

    async componentDidMount() {
        await this.props.get_details('abc1234');
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
        if (prevProps.transactionDetails !== this.props.transactionDetails) {
            console.log("Inside ComponentDidUpdate");
            // It never arrives here, perhaps suggesting the prop is never created in the store?

            this.setState({
                trans_status: this.props.transactionDetails.trans_status,
            });
        }
    }

    render() {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(this.state.trans_status);
        // returns "" instead of the value of the redux action/reducer
        console.log(JSON.stringify(this.props.transactionDetails);
        // returns undefined instead of the value of the redux action/reducer

        // What am I doing wrong? Why am I not getting the transactionDetails here?
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        settings: state.settings,
        // the settings property works fine in this component
        transactionDetails: state.transactionDetails,
    };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return bindActionCreators(
        {get_details}, dispatch
    );
};

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(DonePage));
```

Redux Action:

```
export const get_details = (trans_id) => {
    let token = getAuthToken();
    return (dispatch) => {
        axios
            .get(`${url}/get_details/${trans_id}`, {
                headers: { Authorization: `${token}` },
            })
            .then((res) => {
                if (res.status === 200) {
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(res.data.data);
                    // returns {"trans_status":"paid","trans_due":"0"}
                    return dispatch({
                        type: DETAILS_SUCCESS,
                        payload: res.data.data,
                    });
                } else {
                    return dispatch({
                        type: DETAILS_ERROR,
                        payload: res.data.data,
                    });
                }
            })
    }
}
```

Reducer:

```
import {
    DETAILS_SUCCESS,
    DETAILS_ERROR,
} from "../constants";

const initial_state = {
    transactionDetails: [],
    transactionDetailsError: "",
};

export default function transactionsReducer(state = initial_state, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case DETAILS_SUCCESS:
            console.log(JSON.stringify(action.payload));
            // returns {"trans_status":"paid","trans_due":"0"}
            return { ...state, transactionDetails: action.payload };
        case DETAILS_ERROR:
            return { ...state, transactionDetailsError: action.payload };
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

---

**Update** In the reducers index file (`/reducers/index.js`) I have:

```
const reducers = combineReducers({
    variousVariables: variablesReducer,
    transactions: transactionsReducer,
});
```

It works if I change this to:

```
const reducers = combineReducers({
    variousVariables: variablesReducer,
    transactionDetails: transactionsReducer,
});
```

On the Page, within `render`, `this.props.transactionDetails` now returns data:

```
{"transData":[],"transactionDetails":{"transaction_status":"paid","transaction_amount_due":"0"},"transactionDetailsError":"","otherData":"", etc.}
```

So `transactionDetails` is nested inside another `transactionDetails` and I need to call `this.props.transactionDetails.transactionDetails` or `this.props.transactionDetails.transData`. However, I would like this to be `this.props.transactions.transactionDetails` and `this.props.transactions.transData`.

Can someone explain what is going on? I thought I could just name the keys in the reducers index file anything I like and that then defines the "path" of `this.props.anythingilike`.

Why can I not just change the key in the reducers index file to get what I'm looking for? I guess I need to change something on the Page as well to make it the way I want? Because right now if I change the key in the reducers index file to `transactions`, then `this.props.transactions` is still `undefined` on the Page, while if that key is `transactionDetails` then `this.props.transactionDetails` does return the correct data.

Comment: Sounds like an anti-pattern. Redux is a state management framework. It's going to be rare that you want to keep the same value in local state. Just use the value from redux direclty

Comment: Yeah, I know it's really a newbie question. but how to do that? `this.state.trans_status` still returns `""` on the React page also after calling upon the Redux action. Or does that imply the Redux action is doing something wrong? Essentially what I want to do is call upon the value on the React page for `trans_status` that I can see the controller method is correctly returning.

Comment: No, nothing is going wrong. Just like React state, Redux state will not be updated until the next render. So you would not be able to set the local state in `componentDidMount`. You would have to use a different lifecycle method like `componentDidUpdate` so you could update it on the next render (not exactly sure which one is best, it's been a while now since I've used class components regularly).

Comment: Thank you, I've updated my post with `componentDidUpdate` but I still get an `""` for `this.state.trans_status`.

Comment: Seems like to component is not connected properly. But I couldn't spot any mistake. Is it only this component that's not getting redux state? Some underlying assumption must be wrong. I would try to remove the `withRouter` wrapping to see if that makes a difference.

Comment: There's actually a second property inside `mapStateToProps`, which I've added to my post. The problem is not there inside the component for this `settings` property; that is working as it should. So the problem is only happening for this Component and only for the specific property of `transactionDetails`. Removing the `withRouter` wrapping makes no difference.

Comment: `get_details` is a higher order function so when you call it a function is returned. Doesn't look like you are calling the returned function in `componentDidMount`. Also, did you add redux-thunk middleware?

Comment: @morganney, thanks, can you explain it a little bit further? How could I test if that is indeed the cause of the problem? I thought by calling on the `get_details` function inside `componentDidMount`, as I do now, would automatically set the `props` on the page for the variables that this function fetches.

Comment: `get_details` returns a func so you need middleware to handle actions like that, read the docs for redux-thunk. Also, the action expects a string passed or at least not an object with `payment_id`. Looks like multiple things wrong, but mainly you need to set up support for actions that return funcs, or call the higher order function properly and pass in `dispatch` manually.

Comment: Ah, yes, I do use `redux-thunk`. On other pages I also use similar functions like this without problems. `payment_id` is indeed a string (I'll update that in my post); see the `console.log` lines in the action and reducer, which indicate they seem to work fine.

Comment: Just glanced at the code. It looks like `get_details` accepts a simple number or string as the ID, yet when you call it (indirectly) as `this.props.get_details` in the component, you are passing an object. This may be why the `transactionDetails` prop is never seeing the update you expect. You can easily check what is going on here by looking at what requests are made (and what response you get) in the Network tab of your developer tools. As for `this.state.transStatus`, as others have already said, local component state has *nothing* to do with Redux.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I now understand what you others were referring to. That was my mistake indeed, and I've corrected it in the post, now passing the function a string instead of an object. However, the problem is still the same.

Comment: Why does the action use `DETAILS_SUCCESS` but the reducer `TRANSACTION_DETAILS_SUCCESS`? You've got to show more of your code. If you need help show full details don't assume what code is good and what is bad, just show it all.

Comment: Sorry about that, I've corrected that in the post. In my code base it was already correct.

Comment: I stood up a sample environment in [this codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-redux-37ymkw?file=/src/DonePage.js) where I mostly copied your code (with a few adjustments, like faking the network request), and it works there (i.e. I'm not seeing the issues you mentioned). I suspect that there might be some important details that are missing from your repro - like how you created the redux store and provided it with context. Can you create a working example of the problem on codesandbox?

Comment: Thanks @AndrewStegmaier, I've added an update to the post. It seems there is something going on with the setup of the reducers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution to my question. As suggested by several people there was details about the store setup that were of importance, particularly the setup of the reducers and the use of `combineReducers`.

The setup of my reducers included:

```
const reducers = combineReducers({
    ...,
    transactions: transactionsReducer,
});
```

To make it work, on the Page I only needed to change:

1--`this.props.transactionDetails` to `this.props.transactions` (and `this.props.transactions.transactionDetails` if needed.

2--The last line in the code block below needed to be `transactions: state.transactions`

```
 const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
     return {
         settings: state.settings,
         transactionDetails: state.transactionDetails,
     };
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use it with the method compose from redux library.

```
import {compose} from "redux";

//your code

export default compose(
  withRouter,
  connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)
)(App);
```

Comment: I've tried it with adding `compose` but it made no difference.

Answer (score 0):

`get_details()` is not an async function so no need to await I believe.

Additionally, you can check first if your props is updated on `componentDidupdate` like

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
  console.log(this.props.transactionDetails)
  // if transactionDetails updated then you can perform setState
}
```